# How do i iterate over created objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, javascript-objects

im trying to make a simple form validation, but instead of typing everything out for each element i thought of making an object. but i can't figure out how to loop true all the created object and calling the check method inside the objects constructor.(inside the oclick event)
i looked on google but find articles about iterating true the object values not the objects themself

hope you guy's could help me out i'm still a beginner.
and if you see some bad practises, please send me a message on that so i can correct myself

---

```
var checklink;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7SPc9/

Comment: So, your linked demo has a wall of (non-[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) code and the *only* code you thought might be relevant in your question is `var checklink`? ***Really?*** Voting to close because of a complete lack of effort on your part.

Comment: @DavidThomas that was supposed to cheat SO's filter. Badly needing VTC reason "Violates the rule"

Comment: @Amit: I know, but I was trying to make a point hinting at *why* we need code in the question.

Comment: You want to iterate through all the objects and make that boolean value true?

Comment: hi srry about the var but it's my first time posting on this site and i could't figure out how to post my code because it wouldn't let me

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can store references of your created objects in an array, and then go through them and call any methods on them

```
var array = [];
var object;

// foreach (form fields) {
//     create and initailze the object
//     array.push(object);          
// }

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1){
    yourMethod(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` in form element, like this.

```
submit.onclick = function(){
    var form = document.getElementById("winnerForm"),
        elems = form.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        i, len, elem;

    for (i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
        elem = elems[i];
        // This is the element and its id
        console.log(elem, elem.id);
    }

}
```